# Fire javascript function after get request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 separate javascript functions, the first builds a dropdown list from a JSON feed and then the second fires the Selectric plugin to style the dropdown.

I added a delay to the plugin function but it's a hack so id like to add this function after the get request finishes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.get('scanlistjson',{id:''},function(responseJson) {   
        var $select = $('#scanlist');                              
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {               
          $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);      
        });
      });
  });

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#scanlist').selectric();
}, 300);
```

Comment: So call it in the success callback after you build the select. Do not over think it. :)

Comment: Ah, yes I was massively over thinking it!

Answer (score 4):

You have to call it in the `$.get` call back function after appending the all **option** of **select**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.get('scanlistjson',{id:''},function(responseJson) {   
        var $select = $('#scanlist');                              
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {               
          $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);      
        });
         $('#scanlist').selectric(); // call it here
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the function call inside callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $.get('scanlistjson',{id:''},function(responseJson) {   
            var $select = $('#scanlist');                              
            $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {               
              $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo($select);      
            });
             $('#scanlist').selectric();
          });
      });
```